# Powershell, Python 2.7, virtualenvwrapper not finding virtualenv in PATH. Too dumb to discern answer from prev posts and Google. Please advise.

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have installed virtualenv and the virtualenvwrapper in Powershell for Python 2.7.  I am following the tutorial from Tyler Butler listed here

http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/

This is a great tutorial and I have been successful on everything so far after some Google-Fu here and there.
When I attempt to make a new virtualenv by entering:

```
New-VirtualEnvironment engineer
```

I get an error which reads:

```
virtualenvwrapper could not find virtualenv in your PATH
```

I have noticed there a number of SO posts pertaining to this question and some of them have been informative but nothing has illustrated to me the mistake I am making.

I am a beginner programmer, as you can probably tell.

Steps I have taken:

added virtualenv to my directory path...and that did nothing.
I have looked around in the virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper files for some sort of helpful .txt file but again while informative I could not seem to glean an actual solution.

Any input is appreciated, Please and Thank You for stopping by to read this!

Answer (score 0):

I've just moved from my laptop to a new PC and am having trouble setting up my environment - I can't seem to find the docs I used initially.

That being said, this might help (though it's not the way my initial setup worked):

1. Set up a powershell profile
2. Add "Import-Module virtualenvwrapper" (without quotation marks) to your profile.

As to setting up a profile, there should be documentation floating around. Mine is set up with "posh-git", since I was looking to add git functionality. If you're interested in that, read this: http://jdhnet.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/a-better-git-commandline-by-integrating-git-with-powershell/

However, I'm not sure this addresses your particular error, so do reply if it doesn't work - it might be that you're not adding to the path correctly.

Hope that helps! I'll probably edit it later once I have time to read up on .profiles, but this should suffice! Have fun.